# Graphics card upgrade possible?

Tags: graphics-cards, smps

I bought this PC from Best Buy a few months ago, found it works pretty well on older games like Assassin's Creed II but starts to lack only in Brotherhood. [Here is the the PC](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/ibuypower-desktop-amd-fx-series-8gb-memory-1tb-hard-drive-black/5574049.p?id=1219143550897&skuId=5574049) and here is my [PC Part Picker List](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/TpxwBm).

(please not that some of the items on the list are just place holders because they did not have the actual part that is in the computer...)

I am looking to upgrade to the NVIDIA GTX 970 ASUS STRIX edition and my power supply is 400 Watt ATX. I put all the specs into PC Part Picker and it says that the estimated wattage is 349 Watts for my PC after the upgrade. So, is 50W enough headroom for my upgrade? If not, how many watts would a decent amount of headroom be?

Comment: here is a website that shows you your potential power consumption:
http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator
(don't forget to mark the charge at 105% to be sure ;) )
With that GPU and CPU i'd highly recommence atleast a 550W PSU
Also I do not understand a part of the question. the PC you have is the ibuy power right?
and the PC part picker is the PC you want to build? or add to the current PC?

Comment: It is nearly equivalent to what I currently have but with a lot of place holders

Comment: It appears Neweg's PSU calculator is broken, because it says you need almost 700W, while all the others agree, saying between 350-420

Comment: I am going to settle on the CX500M because I like the reviews and I like the modular idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage should be around 380-390W actually.
Technically speaking the 400W PSU should be enough but you'd better have more headroom a PSU of 450W at the least and 550W to be futur proof.